# Update object of an array in UIViewController from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, object

I have a `UITableViewCell` that I use in several `UITableView`'s that are in differents `UIViewController`'s. From my cell, there is an object that I update but I would like to update it also in the array of my controllers. How ?

For example :

**UITableViewCell :**

```
class NotificationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonRead: UIButton!

    var notification = Notification()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    @IBAction func clickButtonRead(_ sender: Any) {
        self.notification.isRead = true
    }
}
```

**UIViewController :**

```
class NotificationsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    /* List notifications */
    var listNotifications = [Notification]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //View cell
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "viewNotificationTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
        self.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellNotification")

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.listNotifications.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellNotification", for: indexPath) as! NotificationTableViewCell

        cell.notification = self.listNotifications[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**
I can pass the controller and the indexPath to the cell for update the object notification in listNotifications like this : `self.controller.listNotifications[indexPath.row] = self.notification`
But if i use this cell with more controllers, I must cast the controller from cell to know what controller is it.
I am looking for a way to update the object without having to cast the controller.

Comment: Pls xplain more about ur issue.

Comment: Notification is a struct or class ?

Comment: Notification is a class.

Comment: I think once you update the notification object in the cell it should already be updated in the view controller as well. From your code, it looks like it is the same object and you are not creating any copies of it. 
But you should definitely use protocol and delegates for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using protocol
make a protocol in your tableview Cell Class

```
    protocol NotificationDelegate{
       func didReadNotification(notification:Notification , index:Int)
    }
    class NotificationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        @IBOutlet weak var buttonRead: UIButton!
        // and make this optional don't initialize it
        var notification:Notification?
        var delegate:NotificationDelegate?
        var indexOfNotification:Int?
        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
        }

        @IBAction func clickButtonRead(_ sender: Any) {
            self.notification?.isRead = true
            self.delegate?.didReadNotification(notification:self.notification! , index:indexOfNotification!)
        }

}
```

and add NotificationDelegate in you ViewController

```
    class NotificationsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITabBarControllerDelegate , NotificationDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

        /* List notifications */
        var listNotifications = [Notification]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            //View cell
            let nib = UINib(nibName: "viewNotificationTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
            self.tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellNotification")

        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }

        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return self.listNotifications.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellNotification", for: indexPath) as! NotificationTableViewCell

            cell.notification = self.listNotifications[indexPath.row]
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.indexOfNotification = indexPath.row
            return cell
        }

      // This Delegte method will be called whenever user read the notification
      func didReadNotification(notification:Notification , index:Int){
          // do what ever you want here is your index and notification..
          let notification = listNotifications[index] // this is your notification in listNotifications 
      }

}
```

Comment: How I know what is notification in listNotifications ?

Comment: you can pass the index numer the you can get

Answer (score 2):

The ideal way to do it is you create a NotificationTableViewCellDelegate and set the delegate to view controller. In your method clickButtonRead call the delegate method and update the object in the view controller.

```
    protocol NotificationTableViewCellDelegate {
        func enableReadForNotification(notification: Notification)
    }    

    class NotificationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

            @IBOutlet weak var buttonRead: UIButton!
            var notification = Notification()
            weak var delegate: NotificationTableViewCellDelegate?

            override func awakeFromNib() {
                super.awakeFromNib()
            }

            @IBAction func clickButtonRead(_ sender: Any) {
                self.notification.isRead = true
               if let delegate = self.delegate {
                  delegate.enableReadForNotification(self.notification)
               }
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps!